# Is every finite group an extension?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

I would like to know if every finite group is an extension of some group by another. Thanks

Comment: Every group is an extension of itself by the trivial group. Or, do you mean something else?

Comment: Or of the trivial group by itself. =]

Comment: The group with one element is an extension of itself by itself, but that is not very interesting.  A group with two elements is an extension of itself by a group of one element, but that is still not very interesting.  To be an interesting extension, it must have a normal subgroup that has more than one element, but not all of the elements.  The groups that are not interesting extensions are called simple groups.

Comment: @Jack:  I think that would probably do for an answer (perhaps including an example of a simple group).

Answer (score 8):

The group with one element is an extension of itself by itself, but that is not very interesting. A group with two elements is an extension of itself by a group of one element, but that is still not very interesting. To be an interesting extension, it must have a normal subgroup that has more than one element, but not all of the elements. The groups that are not interesting extensions are called [simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group), though usually the group with one element is not considered simple, but "trivial".

For example the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of integers mod *p*, where *p* is a prime are all simple groups.

The [orientation-preserving symmetries  of a regular icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_group) are a simple group of order 60.